# Asp.net MVC 3 - Data Validation

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, validation

I'm new at ASP.NET MVC web framework. My database is compound of a single model class("Movie"). I need to validate user's from entering existing data, for instance, a database row could be:

- Title - "Indiana Jones and the lost Arc"
- Price - $10.00

If another user tries to insert into the database the same data above, provide an error message and prevent from submitting the form collection.

Comment: Doesn't the book show you examples?

Comment: You can do the naive validation on when the control to enter the data is fired. Simply check each time(again this is naive but should get you going). What have you actually tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I think that your question need a "program as answer" but I'll try to suggest you from where to start for working with validation. Suppose you have this model:

```
class Movie {
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    [Required(ErrorMessage="Title is required.")]
    [Remote("UniqueTitle", "Validation")]
    public String Title { get; set; }
    [Required(ErrorMessage="Price is required.")]
    public float Price { get; set; }
}
```

You can decorate it for "simple validation" using Data Annotation. I've used a specific attribute, called [Remote](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg508808%28vs.98%29.aspx).

This attribute allow you to define a custom, server-side, logic to validate the model.

Now, you can create a validation controller where check that provided value is not already in use:

```
class ValidationController : Controller {

    private IDbContext db = ...;
    public ActionResult UniqueTitle(String title) {
        var item = db.Movies.FirstOrDefault(m => m.Title.Equals(title));
        return Json(item == null, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
}
```

Now you are ready to validate your model. 
I hope this can help.